# Double Buffering dramatically slows performance

Tags: java, swing, awt

Edit: I know this code isn't good, I'm just curious as to Why exactly it is SO bad, when it was taken from an ostensibly reputable source: [http://www.amazon.com/Killer-Game-Programming-Andrew-Davison/dp/0596007302](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007302)

I've been working on a grid-based game that has thus far used passive animation, that is, everything is redrawn whenever the user presses a button (characters pop forward a square). Once I got the mechanics working well, I went back and introduced an active rendering loop that takes an FPS value and creates an appropriate UPS, skipping frames if needed to maintain the appropriate UPS.

Everything worked well at first, the FPS/UPS would stay stable/close to one another even past values of 100FPS, but when I tried to implement double-buffering the FPS shot down to about 17, while the UPS remained close to my desired setting!

I've done my research, and I have a secondary, perhaps more opinion-y question below, but my main question is **why is this causing such a massive performance hit?**

The following two methods are called each animation loop.

```
public void buildWorld(){
    if (dbImage == null){
          dbImage = createImage(pWidth, pHeight);
          if (dbImage == null) {
              System.out.println("dbImage is null");
              return;
          }
          else{
              dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
          }
    }
    //When the above statements are commented out, and the following line
    //Is used without the paintScreen method, a very high FPS is achieved.
    //dbg = this.getGraphics();

    dbg.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    dbg.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    //various other things are drawn...
}
private void paintScreen(){ 
    Graphics g;
    try {
      g = this.getGraphics();
      if ((g != null) && (dbImage != null)){
          g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null);
      }
      g.dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { System.out.println("Graphics context error: " + e);  }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Why does this cause an 80% or more loss of FPS?

Now onto some secondary questions. I've based my design so far on "Killer Game Programming in Java" an interesting but outdated book. I'm drawing to a JPanel within a JScrollPane, which gives me some nice click'n'drag, RTS like control of the battlefield, but has made it difficult to implement many of the double-buffering solutions I've been reading about. Basically I've decided that I'm going to have to completely overhaul my design to get over this issue, so the questions remain:

Assuming I want the program to be able to run both windowed and fullscreen, which rendering method would offer the highest performance?

a) an AWT canvas + a JFrame

b) an AWT frame

c) directly to a JFrame

d) how I'm doing it is fine, barring some mistake

Also, I see lots of vague talk about never mixing AWT and Swing, but almost every tutorial I see combines the two at some point. Is this really that bad, or only in certain circumstances?

Comment: Rendering to an image should work fine, but now you have to tweak java2d a little bit. E.g. do you create a compatible image? Did you disable the RepaintManager for this panel? (I had to do this with Full screen exclusive mode) Another nice book is Developing Games in Java it also outdated but some of the core concept are still valide (because swing is still around (-: ) On a side note, I would stay away from swing game programming and try to use libgdx or javafx in generel.

Comment: I do disable the repaint manager, but I'm not sure what you mean by compatible image, is there a term I could use to research it further?

I'll look into libgdx and javafx, but the game is relatively straightforward (and my first) so I was trying to keep it as simple as I could.

Any idea why the method I used would be so slow?

Comment: Also, if Swing shouldn't be used for game development, what about AWT? Is that also too outdated for the medium? Because that was the alternative I was about to implement...

Comment: You're creating quite a contradictory situation here. Basically you want to think you're using Swing, but you're disabling all features that make Swing work so you can do your own thing. Then ditch Swing and use a plain AWT Canvas with a BufferedStrategy.

Comment: I don't "want to think" anything, I was following a very highly reviewed, albeit old, guide to making this sort of thing. I already said I planned on going AWT, so I just want to make sure you are actually suggesting that as a viable option, and not sarcastically saying that this is also a bad option.

Comment: `GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage(width, height)` or
`GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage(width, height, transparency)` from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html it may help or not

Comment: It does, thank you morpheus!

Comment: @dGFisher you're inventing the sarcasm bit, no need to be defensive. I would like to see this "highly reviewed" guide you speak of, is it online somewhere?

Comment: "Killer Game Programming in Java" http://www.amazon.com/Killer-Game-Programming-Andrew-Davison/dp/0596007302 I know it's old as heck, but  multiple people, online and not, recommended it to me. After studying a bit of non-game related java I made a game with passive rendering, then tried to apply the animation framework touted by this book. Sorry if I invented the sarcasm, I've been getting nothing but snarky responses. I already planned on using pure AWT once I saw how poorly the book's code worked, but I wanted to make sure that I wasn't being mislead into wasting more time. Mea Culpa.

Comment: While the 3D libraries in "Killer Game Programming in Java" are dated, the techniques described are not.  A JPanel is already double buffered, so your paintComponent method just draws to the panel.  You can draw to a BufferedImage, then draw the BufferedImage to the JPanel, but you're not really gaining anything by doing so.  We really can't help you much unless you post a short, self-contained, **runnable** example of your problem.